# Adding Azure Web App Service Custom Domain during Devops Deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

An App Service custom domain requires validation at deployment time which in turn requires a DNS CNAME to point to the new app service name. The app service name is, however, created dynamically, so we do not know the name it will have at deployment time. This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain almost solves the problem but it also requires you to know the app service name prior to deployment.

I have tried an App Gateway instead to sit in front of the App Service and editing the URLs in in a rewrite rule. This partially works but unfortunately, it has a documented bug where if there are many Set-Cookie to rewrite, it rewrites the first and deletes the rest. Therefore, we cannot rewrite headers on the App Gateway (until such time as MS fix the bug) and have instead to send the public URL all the way to the back end App Service, hence why we need the custom domain defined on the App Service itself.

The question is: how do I create a Custom Domain on an App Service the the time of deployment using Azure Devops if I do not know the name of the App Service until it is created?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is Simon's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Hi Hugh. No, Simon's suggestion does not work. Are you please able to confirm that Azure Devops and Custom Domains (with app name chosen at deployment time) are incompatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this more of a "workaround of a serious limitation" than a true "answer" because although Microsoft have recently made some changes to the verification process, they do still require verification, which works against the ethos of a CI/CD pipeline. My hope is that in the future, they allow trusted processes to bypass the domain ownership verification. In the meantime, as a workaround, we simply moved the DNS to Microsoft themselves - namely Azure DNS. Azure DNS meets our HA requirements but note that it does not (yet) support DNSSec. Once that was done, we modified our pipeline thus:

- Deploy App Service (via ARM template in our case but the CLI would suffice)
- Parse the name via the ARM Output to create a variable from the App Service name (via a bash script in our case)
- Create a single awverify CNAME record in Azure DNS (using the CLI)
- Add a 60 second delay task
- Do all the other pipeline tasks at this point (we have quite a few so it eats up time)
- Add the custom domain name to the App Service (using the CLI)
- Upload and bind the SSL certificate (again using the CLI)

In this case, there is enough of a gap between the awverify record and the custom domain name tasks. We have run this pipeline many times and not had a failure (well, not for this reason anyway! ;-) ), so it it possible that the 60 second delay can be lowered. I believe that having it in Azure DNS also helps reduce the delay, though I have not proven this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue as you, OP - and like you, I felt it was utterly pointless to attempt applying custom DNS config through a pipeline at all if it was necessary to create the DNS record by hand. What's the point of CI/CD then?!

My company's DNS runs through Cloudflare, so my solution to this problem is...

- Create an API Token in Cloudflare with permission to manage DNS for the domain in question - stored in Azure Key Vault, and injected into the pipeline with a variable group (via a service connection)
- Deploy an initial ARM template that contains just the resources, including the App Service(s), *without* any DNS config applied
- The initial ARM template declares output variables for the website name, app service plan name, custom domain verification ID, and anything else needed further down in the pipeline
- I wrote a PowerShell script that takes the output variables from the previous step, and makes REST calls to Cloudflare to check if the CNAME and TXT records exist - if they don't, create them. If they do, update them. (Because maybe something changed!)
- Deploy a second ARM template that simply applies the custom domain config to any app services it needs to

I have currently got my pipeline to the point where its updating DNS in Cloudflare - I have an error in the second template deployment, because I forgot to pass its parameters, heh.

It's not 100% ideal, but it's a solid workaround, IMO, and requires no manual steps. I'll report back when I'm completely finished with it, and I'm happy to share code snippets at that time if you need them.

EDIT: This solution appears to have worked! I've deployed the app I was working with to two brand new environments that had no resources provisioned at all, and no pre-existing DNS entries. Everything worked perfectly!

EDIT2: I should mention, I went through this process a second time for a different project - but I used Terraform instead, and it was a far smoother experience! No need to mess with PowerShell or nested deployments at all! Everything just worked! :)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I revisited this last week as it moved up the priority stack and in fact I got something working at the end of last week that is very similar to what you said but in a single pipeline (I cheated!). I think the right thing to do is for me to hit the "Answer your question" button and explain what I did there, so I shall do that.

Comment: I should mention, I went through this process a second time for a different project - but I used Terraform instead, and it was a far smoother experience! No need to mess with PowerShell or nested deployments at all! Everything just worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are a couple of options, there is [ARM template support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-custom-domain-and-ssl) or a [CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-configure-custom-domain).  Both of which can be automated from Azure DevOps using either the [AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops) task or the [AzureCLI@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) task respectively.

Note that when you create an app service it is possible to specify the name as long as it is unique (see [CLI ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-create) or the [first parameter in the ARM template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-custom-domain-and-ssl/azuredeploy.json#L5-L10)).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, the ARM templates have the precisely the constraint in that they requirement validation prior to deployment. I confess I haven't tried the CLI (or indeed direct use of REST). For completeness, I will try them.

Comment: No, CLI doesn't work: "A TXT record pointing from asuid.testhost.contoso.com to 57a84ad06c4860292aa5eec9a295b0fb60386cef4d3ead6a9c7a0669ab87d20e was not found. Alternative CNAME record awverify.testhost.contoso.com to awverify.mywebapp.azurewebsites.net was not found either."

Comment: Can you specify the name of the app at creation time?  The ARM template's first parameter is webAppName.

Comment: The pipeline itself creates the app name. Once it is created, we know what the name is (e.g. as the output of the pipeline). By then, it's to late. Well, unless we manually create the DNS record and then manually add the custom domain, but that defeats the point of CD pipelines! Your suggestion only works if you pre-define what the app name will be. But even then, you still have to create the DNS entry prior to deployment which I still think is a serious omission and negates the point of CD.

Comment: I personally think it's fine to rely on a known app name before deployment time. If not you can create the custom domain programtically using the Azure CLI after the initial deployment. Not sure what DNS provider you're using, but if it's something like CloudFlare you'll be able to call an API to create that too.

Comment: It's not about not knowing the app name out of choice. FYI, CI and CD pipelines create many objects during deployment and we don't always know the object name the pipeline will create prior to deployment. This is true of devops, terraform, cloud formation, pulumi - you name it. App Services are no different to, say a NIC in the pipeline sense. IOW, I think what you are saying that the answer to the OP is "not possible".

Comment: A 3 stage pipeline: 1. deploy app service 2. create DNS validation records programatically 3. wait up to 48 hours (MS words, not mine) 4. Add custom domain won't result in a pipeline in this instance.